# how to generate random data in json from python faker?

Tags: python, json

I want to generate 5 test cases which gives random data in json format as given below.

```
{
    "password2": "password@123",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "username": "user123",
    "first_name": "first",
    "last_name": "last",
    "phone":"1234567890",
    "city":"Paris",
    "about":"This is information about developer"
}
```

The code below gives 5 test cases, but with similar details. I want to generate 5 different test case with all different details.
Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
from faker import Faker
import random


class LoginData:
    fake = Faker()
    password = "password@123"
    email = fake.email()
    username = fake.first_name()
    first_name = fake.first_name()
    last_name = fake.last_name()
    phone = random.randint(9000000000, 9999999999)
    city = fake.city()
    about = "This is a sample text : about"

    def get_json(self):
        p = {
            'password': self.password,
            'email': self.email,
            'username': self.first_name,
            'first_name': self.first_name,
            'last_name': self.last_name,
            'phone': self.phone,
            'city': self.city,
            'about': self.about
        }
        return p


logindata = LoginData()


def input_data(x):
    for i in range(0, x):
        print(logindata.get_json())


def main():
    no_of_input = 5
    input_data(no_of_input)


main()
```

Comment: There's no JSON in your question, only `dict`s. Do you *need* JSON?

Comment: The output of the python code should be in JSON format.

Comment: Are you aware of the `json` module in the standard library?

Comment: This question appears to be solely about how to generate JSON from a given `dict`; how that `dict` was generated isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you want to generate different data every time. To do that, you need to:

- Currently the `LoginData` attributes are generated when the class is defined. If you want them to be different for each instance, make them instance attributes and set them in the `__init__()` method.
- You need to create a new `LoginData` instance in every iteration of the for loop in `input_data()`.

Code:

```py
from faker import Faker
import random


class LoginData:

    def __init__(self):
        fake = Faker()
        self.password = "password@123"
        self.email = fake.email()
        self.username = fake.first_name()
        self.first_name = fake.first_name()
        self.last_name = fake.last_name()
        self.phone = random.randint(9000000000, 9999999999)
        self.city = fake.city()
        self.about = "This is a sample text : about"

    def get_json(self):
        p = {
            'password': self.password,
            'email': self.email,
            'username': self.first_name,
            'first_name': self.first_name,
            'last_name': self.last_name,
            'phone': self.phone,
            'city': self.city,
            'about': self.about
        }
        return p



def input_data(x):
    for i in range(0, x):
        logindata = LoginData()
        print(logindata.get_json())


def main():
    no_of_input = 5
    input_data(no_of_input)


main()
```

Note that `get_json()` still returns a Python dict, not JSON. For JSON, you can use the `json` module in the standard library:

```py
import json
```

and in `get_json()`

```py
return json.dumps(p)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for.